# How can I check what is blocking Apache from connecting to outside servers?

Tags: windows, apache, wamp, firewall, windows-firewall

I've had a WAMP setup on Windows 7 and working fine for years. A few weeks ago, I ran an aggressive spyware scanner that tightened all sorts of security on my computer. Since then I've been having trouble with sites running on my localhost not being able to connect to outside servers. I suspect that it has something to do with connections being refused by Apache or by Windows, but I don't have the slightest idea where to start looking for problems. Can anyone here help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Open your firewall settings and allow incomming connections through port 80.